# Making macOS bootable USB stuck on "Making disk bootable"

Tags: macos, terminal, usb, startup, ventura

I've followed the instructions in "[Create a bootable installer for macOS](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201372)" to create a bootable macOS USB installer using the following command:

```
sudo /Applications/Install\ macOS\ Ventura.app/Contents/Resources/createinstallmedia --volume /Volumes/MyVolume
```

But the terminal is stuck on `Making disk bootable...`. I've tried several times to no avail. Any ideas?

Comment: Have you tried a different USB or different slot?  In my experience I was creating a bootable USB and I had to let it run all night.  It eventually finished.  The USB worked fine and was fast enough.

Comment: @CraigHindall That seemed to be the problem. No idea why it was so slow. It took around 9 hours to make the USB, but it worked once complete.

Comment: mine took so long! i think letting the computer sleep was pausing it... i did an older OS and it was mad fast (sierra) but this monterey disk is mad slow. the thumb drive is also way too large, 64gb, maybe that's somehow affecting

Comment: @austin Thanks for your input - certainly useful for anyone else who finds this problematic and lands here... It definitely seems like there's something Apple can improve on with regards to this. Hopefully they are aware and can fix in a future release.

Comment: It's been stuck at 'Copying the MacOS RecoveryOS..." for an hour now for me as well. I am on a MB14 M2 Pro, and the target usb drive is a 128 GB Sandisk stick. Is it really normal to take this long? Also, the machine is already on Ventura, but when I downloaded the installer from the App Store, it just stayed open and there is no way to close it. Is that normal?

Comment: @Ruffy I'd be inclined to leave it running overnight. It's normal, in the sense of, it just takes that long, but it's atrocious all the same. Thumbs down to Apple on that one.

Answer (score 3):

Once after executing the command

```
sudo /Applications/Install\ macOS\ Ventura.app/Contents/Resources/createinstallmedia --volume /Volumes/Install\ macOS\ Ventura
```

After this step

```
Erasing disk: 0%... 10%... 20%... 30%... 100%
```

you disk will mount back.

Run this command in another terminal and wait for sometime.

```
mdutil -i off -d /Volumes/Install\ macOS\ Ventura
```

Then it will start working.

Comment: This should be the answer

Answer (score 0):

If you are still facing some issues, here are my findings; it sounds so illogical even to me but somehow it worked.
I was running this command to make a Big Sur USB bootable (installer) while my OS was Monterey 12.5.1 (terminal).

When you format a USB drive in Disk Utility, it gives you two drop-downs to select options.
The first drop-down has options APFS, APFS encrypted, Mac OS Extended (Journaled), etc.
The second drop-down has three options

1. GUID Partition Map
2. Master Boot Record
3. Apple Partition Map
   According to your choice in the second drop-down, the first drop-down options will change.

We need Mac OS Extended (Journaled) for bootable media under the first drop-down, however, this option comes no matter what you choose in the second drop-down.

But it only worked for me when I chose the second drop-down as Master Boot Record. I was trying before GUID Partition Map and every time it was stuck in Terminal. Not sure, maybe it is working too, but it could be very, very slow; I waited for more than hours twice, with no progress at all. I killed the terminal command twice.

But on the third attempt after selecting Master Boot Record as the partition map scheme, it was a bit slow in Terminal around 40 mins but it worked.

The funny thing is internally (my guess) it creates an Apple Partition Map under all schemes yet gets stuck on the terminal.

So I think if you are stuck in Terminal after 'copying to disk...' message then wait for some time maybe one hour or around 40 mins, you should see copying to disk progress to at least 30%, if not restart it.

But make sure you choose Master Boot Record as a partition map. I did not try with the Apple Partition Map because it worked for me with Master Boot Record, if it will not then I will go for the third option (fourth try) and try with the Apple Partition Map option.

Why it sounds so illogical because internally all three are probably Apple Partition Map only. I have no clue why it worked and why it did not with other options.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same issue with SanDisk 128GB Ultra Fit USB 3.1 Flash Drive.

When I changed to use ADATA 16GB USB 3.0 Flash Drive, the whole process finished within 20 minutes. I can keep seeing disk space changes or progress changes.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://apple.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://apple.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/345703)